# Why the loop runs only 1 time instead of reaching the end of the file?

Tags: bash, unix, sh, exec

I am needing to read the file "namespace.txt" and execute "exec" for each line that the file contains, but only the first line of the txt is executed :(

Txt file:

```
ocp_namespace_1
...    
ocp_namespace_n
```

Bash file:

```
while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ]
do
   echo ${p}
   exec velero schedule create ${p} --schedule="@every 6h" --include-namespaces ${p} --ttl 240h0m0s
done < namespaces.txt
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: Why do you use `exec`?

Comment: to execute the command "velero......." with the content of every line in txt file

Comment: For more details: `help exec`

Comment: @AdrianEzequielMartinez : By design, `exec` replaces the current process by a new one, thereby effectively stopping everything, including your loop. You need to run your command as child process.

Answer (score 0):

because `exec` replaces the script with the executed command; from `man exec`:

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

and the bash builtin `exec` is an interface to this:

> Execute COMMAND, replacing this shell with the specified program.
> Blockquote

So it never returns to complete the loop.  As other commenters have suggested, simply remove the word `exec`.

Comment: In fact it never returns to bash because the bash process no longer exists.

Comment: the process does in fact still exist, but the memory is replaced with a different binary image and execution starts anew.  execve() can fail to complete this step (example if no binary handler for the executable format is found), and the kernel will deliver a SIGSEGV to ensure that it never returns back to bash (see fs/exec.c 'out' label).